# Using Power Automate, how do you read a "Flow variable" into a Python Script

Tags: power-automate, rpa

Using Microsoft Power Automate Desktop (PAD), I have captured a moderately long string called ExtractPDFText.  I can display the text in a message window, now I need it to run through Python Script.

In the Power Automate Desktop application's python input box I am just trying to get it to run this:

```
x = str(%ExtractedPDFText%)
print("work")
```

But it keeps returning an "unexpected token"

[image]

How should I be reading this variable?  I tried with and without the str() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping in the string in quotation marks

Comment: Thanks.  While the one set of quotes didn't work, triple quotes did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fleshed out answer - thanks to the comment from user2502794.  Start by writing a Python script which works in Python:

[image]

This just returns all the strings in a list which contain the letter "s".

Now in Power Automate Desktop, set the value of a test variable:

[image]

Add a Python script action:

[image]

You could now display the value of the output, as captured in the PAD variable:

[image]

This would give this for our example:

[image]

What I can't do is work out how to return a list, rather than string representation of a list.  I suspect the answer is that I now have to remove the square brackets and use a PAD **Split text** action, but this seems clunky, but I'm excited to be able to do all my text processing in Python now (watching PAD looping over the items in a list wasn't that exciting ...).

Answer (score -1):

yes, the sol is triple quotes - """ %value% """

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).